# Allow duplicated tags in bootstrap vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am in trouble with using duplicated tags in bootstrap Vue.

I am using the form tags in bootstrap Vue.
I cannot add the same value inside existing values.

`['apple', 'orange', 'banana']`

For example, I cannot add a new value of "apple" if the value of "apple" is already in the value array. This is because the form tag checks duplicated values and blocks to add them to the value array.

How can I add the same value to this array?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-tags v-model="value" no-outer-focus class="mb-2">
      <template v-slot="{ tags, inputAttrs, inputHandlers, tagVariant, addTag, removeTag }">
        <b-input-group class="mb-2">
          <b-form-input
            v-bind="inputAttrs"
            v-on="inputHandlers"
            placeholder="New tag - Press enter to add"
            class="form-control"
          ></b-form-input>
          <b-input-group-append>
            <b-button @click="addTag()" variant="primary">Add</b-button>
          </b-input-group-append>
        </b-input-group>
        <div class="d-inline-block" style="font-size: 1.5rem;">
          <b-form-tag
            v-for="tag in tags"
            @remove="removeTag(tag)"
            :key="tag"
            :title="tag"
            :variant="tagVariant"
            class="mr-1"
          >{{ tag }}</b-form-tag>
        </div>
      </template>
    </b-form-tags>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        value: ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are looping over a string array and using array elements as `key`. Please read [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State):

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item

Notice **"you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item"**, but you are doing opposite and using array element as key, to handle this case you can always use the `index` from the loop, because index is unique for each element so:

```
<b-form-tag
  v-for="(tag, index) in tags"
  @remove="removeTag(tag)"
  :key="index"
  :title="tag"
  :variant="tagVariant"
  class="mr-1"
>{{ tag }}</b-form-tag>
</div>
```

Now this will not give you duplicate items error :)

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, but I still get the same trouble. I think your answer fits for the normal tag(ex <div> <b-card> etc...), however <b-form-tab> has a logic not to allow a use in order to input same value to array(this.value).

Comment: You mean `b-form-tab` doesn't allow you to have multiple same values?

Comment: yes, it doesn't allow to add the same values to b-form-tag(sorry for typos) not b-form-tab.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't support multiple tags, but there is one way you can use objects instead of strings, but `b-form-tag` doesn't support object syntax yet, here's the [issue link](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/4617). Once it start supporting objects it will be possible to use multiple same tags.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and detailed explanation. Thanks again!!

Comment: If this answer helps you please accept it. Thanks.